# Application Crash on API 23 during use of FusedLocationApi

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fusedlocation

Actually i created a application to show the nearest Fuel station, so i use the FusedLocationApi for that, and in the code first i check the use location is enabled or not, If no than i build GoogleClient and call `setingsrequest()` function and if location is ON than application works perfectly but when location OFF than aaplication is crash.. please check logs

logs :

> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient
>   is not connected yet.
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcc.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcw.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbco.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcca.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                               at
>   activities.FuelStations.onConnected(FuelStations.java:356)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zzn(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbco.zzm(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcc.zzpY(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcc.onConnected(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcw.onConnected(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbbh.onConnected(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.onConnected(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzn.zzrj(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.zzs(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.zzrk(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Updated code:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate ...............................");
        //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fuel_stations);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        final boolean enabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(!enabled) {

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            setingsrequest();
        }
        else
        {

            init();


        }



    }


    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void setingsrequest()
    {

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.

                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(FuelStations.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch (requestCode) {
// Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Location is on",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        init();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                       //keep asking if imp or do whatever
                        finish();
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void init(){

        mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        tempGoogleMap = mGoogleMap;
        //MAP_FLAG=1;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();

            } else {
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        } else {

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
            //the below listener is depreceated so i have  to find a different way
            // mGoogleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(myLocationChangeListener);
            mGoogleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {

                    Location loc = mGoogleMap.getMyLocation();
                    LatLng currentLoc = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
                    mGoogleMap.clear();
                    markerOptions.position(currentLoc);
                    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));

                    mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLoc,15.0f));
                    nearestFuelStation();
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                        .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(FuelStations.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {


        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // location-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        } startLocationUpdates();
        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(mLocation == null){
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (mLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
        } else {
            // Toast.makeText(this, "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        if (i == CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (i == CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network lost. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connection Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }
        if (mGoogleMap!=null)
        mGoogleMap.clear();
        //Place current location marker
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));

        mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15.0f));

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
        nearestFuelStation();

    }

    private void nearestFuelStation() {
        String FuelStation = "gas_station";

    }

    private String getUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String nearbyPlace) {

                }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        if(mGoogleApiClient != null){
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
     }
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("client value", String.valueOf(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();



    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);

        if(mGoogleApiClient!=null){

            {
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();}
            }

        super.onStop();
    }



    // Trigger new location updates at interval
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // Create the location request
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        // Request location updates
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                    mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Better check the connection before going to request. Its because of GoogleApiClient got disconnected. After disconnect calling request throw this error java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.

Comment: but i disconnect only in onPause() method

Comment: You should instantiate a client object in your Activity's onCreate(Bundle) method and then call connect() in onStart() and disconnect() in onStop(), regardless of the state.

Comment: After disconnect why would you requestLocationUpdates. So better check the connection like this if(this.googleApiClient != null){
            this.googleApiClient.connect();
    }

Comment: so you have to wait for the onConnected() callback before mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() will return true and you can use the GoogleApiClient to request the location updates.

Comment: oky sir let me try

Comment: in onConnected, when i check the client status it returns true so where i have to request for the location updates(requestLocationUpdates)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access location before mGoogleApiClient is connected,call setingsrequest() method from onConnected method that executed on mGoogleApiClient  is connected

replace

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }
```

with

```
 @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
     LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        final boolean enabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (!enabled) {
            setingsrequest();
        } else {
            init();

        }
    }
```

Comment: check upadated code... and now when Location is On app crash but when  location dialog is prompt than app is working fine..
and this problem is arise only on the API 23